# split a multiple page pdf with multiple pages to individual pdfs based on a string and save using that string python

Tags: javascript, python

I have a single invoices pdf with multiple invoices inside it, the pdf is organized in such a way that some page has invoice number and that invoice detail continues to a second or third page. What I want to do is split the pdf into individual pdf files based on the invoice number, for example, the total number of pages =  10.

page 1 : invoice 1 continued to page 2
page 3 : invoice 2 continued to page 4
page 5 : invoice 3 continued to page 6
page 7 : invoice 4 continued to page 8
page 9 : invoice 5 continued to page 10

i want to split if the page contains the word invoice then split it with pages before the next invoice word, for the output i am looking for is :
invoice 1.pdf (2 pages page 1 to 2)
invoice 2.pdf (2 pages page 3 to 4)
invoice 3.pdf (2 pages page 5 to 6)
invoice 4.pdf (2 pages page 7 to 8)
invoice 5.pdf (2 pages page 9 to 10)

I got the following code online for splitting pdf into individual files,
can anyone help to extend this to include the above split logic?

````
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("invoices.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get an application to do this , Its called PDF Content Split SA